# forge domain for firefox password autocomplete?

Tags: php, firefox, passwords, domain-name

When running two different websites, say `free.webhost.com/app1` and `free.webhost.com/app2`, it seems that Firefox has trouble storing different login credentials for both, especially when the same username is used with different passwords. If a user's credentials on the `/app1` site are `Name` and `pass1` and on the other site are `Name` and `pass2`, then Firefox can only store one of these and will ask to change the password when hopping between them.

I investigated this problem and to my astonishment this seems to be a WONTFIX in the firefox bug repository: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=263387

Is there any way I can workaround this when designing my apps? Like by setting a certain cookie property in PHP or html, or even specify a (fake) different domain name, so that firefox no longer considers `free.webhost.com/app1` and `free.webhost.com/app2` as the same website for password storage (and can thus store a different password with the same username for both sites)?

Comment: I'd say that either the two apps have the SAME user database, which means the same username and password. Or they have different databases - this case simply use either two different usernames with individual passwords, or use the same password with only one username.

Comment: They have a different database, but most users tend to pick the same username on both when they can (but often with different passwords).

Comment: Its counter-intuitive for two different pages on the same site to use different credentials.

Comment: It's not the same site, it's two different sites hosted on the same domain.

Comment: @user1111929, No. Its two different *apps* on the same site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need a `custom saver`. I'm going to try be short and concise.

This is very useful **if you don't want the browser saver**. I think it can have some applications.

---

**THE BASIC**

I suggest in the PHP we use **different cookies** to save the session with [`session_name`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.session-name.php) or [`session.name directive`](http://php.net/manual/es/session.configuration.php#ini.session.name). For each site we must set a session name.

In the HTML we should use **different inputs `name`**, so the app1 input will be `<input type='email' name='email_app1' />` and app2 `email_app2`. We also can disable the [`autocomplete`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/common-input-element-attributes.html#the-autocomplete-attribute).

The data is saved locally **encrypted** with [`AES`](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard). For this we can get [CryptoJS](https://code.google.com/p/crypto-js/).
We also want to have **[`salt hash`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_(cryptography))** in the client.

**THE CONCEPT (summarized)**:

- Save locally the `password` encrypted. It is returned **by the login
  controller**. Of course if the user wants.
- Save a [`salt`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_(cryptography)) which changes in each login. Of course if the user wants.
- When the user return to the login page, **the JavaScript** checks if there
  is a **salt** and it **sends it to server**. The PHP returns the **passphrase** and **JavaScript** decrypts the local password.

**the sample code**:

In the controller:

```
// I use functions in the controller like example
public function getLoginPage(){
   // it prints the html and js to login using the basics how i have said
}

// salt is sended by the JavaScript
public function getPassphrase( $salt, $username ){
   $passPhrase = get_passphrase_from_salt( $salt, $username, Request::IP() );
   return $passPhrase;
}

// It is to get the salt
public function getSalt( $username, $password ){
      $user = get_user( $username, $password );

      // if valid user...
      $passphrase = random_string();
      $salt = random_string();

      $encrypted = encrypt( $password, md5($passphrase) );

      save_in_table_salt( $salt, $passphrase, $username, Request::IP() );

      // it prints a JSON like example
      return json_encode( array( 'salt' => $salt, 'encrypted' => $encrypted) );
}

// ... Normal login etc you could change the salt and reset in the client
```

In the view we put the **JavaScript logic**. I used [`localstorage`](http://www.w3.org/TR/webstorage/) but I think it's not important.

```
// in login page
window.onload = function(){
    if( localStorage.getItem('salt') !== null ) { // the data is saved
       // Get the passphrase
       ajax_call('post', 'getPassphrase', { 
             salt: localStorage.getItem('salt'),
             username: localStorage.getItem('username')
          }, function( passphrase ){
          // It sets the inputs values!
          document.getElementById('username_app1').value = localStorage.getItem('username');
          document.getElementById('password_app1').value = decrypt( localStorage.getItem('password'), CryptoJS.MD5(passphrase) );
       });
    }
};

// it captures the submit action
document.getElementById('login_form').onsubmit = function(){
    // it asks to user if he wants save locally the credentials
    if( localStorage.getItem('salt') === null
        && confirm('Do you want save credentials?') ){
        var form = this;
        // get salt
        ajax_call('post', 'getSalt', {
              user: document.getElementById('username_app1').value,
              password: document.getElementById('password_app1').value
           }, function( object ){
           localStorage.setItem('salt', object.salt);
           localStorage.setItem('password', object.encrypted);
           localStorage.setItem('username', document.getElementById('username_app1').value );

           form.submit(); // now yes
        });
        return false; // it prevents submit
    }
};
```

You must know that the code is a sample. Some functions don't exists and **it's only to be understood**. We need more conditions and logic to do it works.

**UPDATED**: Now works with multiple computers and IP security and more!

Comment: The "local encryption" is entirely useless if you can just ask the server for the decryption key whenever you like.

Comment: I don't know where you see the problem. You have a **salt** which have a passphrase to decrypt your password saved locally. To get the passphrase **you need the salt, the username and the same IP**. If your IP has changed you would need to introduce the credentials.

I think that go to Configuration->Credentials->Show passwords is less secure. Of course if you see a XSS vulnerability or a way to get the password watching the network say me please.

Comment: That is an interesting idea, I didn't know about JavaScript's local storage ability. This way one can indeed write their own password manager that circumvents the browswer's one. Thanks for the elaborate answer, that definitely earned the bounty! I'm still interested in people's opinions on security though (e.g. whether other sites could 'steal' the stored data if they wanted), as this would be somewhat new domain for me with using the local storage.

Comment: Other sites can't access to your webpage data. This method is secure although somebody watch the network traffic (with http is even better of course!). I am waiting for a the @downvoter's comment

Answer (score 8):

No, there is no workaround or trick for this. Deploy your apps to different domains - even different subdomains (e.g. `app1.example.com` and `app2.example.com`) will do.

Answer (score 1):

There is no workaround for this as internal credential storage in Firefox is organized per domain, not per URL.
Even changing Name or ID for input HTML controls or Form tag will not affect this.

Only solution is to host your application on different (sub)domains.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the best solution here would be to create 2 different virtual host for your app.
Like one for webhost.com and one for free.webhost.com.

[How To Set Up Apache Virtual Hosts on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-12-04-lts)

Hope this help!!

If your are having problem on setting up your virtual host in your server let me know.

Note:You need to create your DNS entry to access the new host you created or you need to add a record to the host file of your system from where you are browsing the site.